# 12V 1A DC input filter

Tags: filter, ac-dc, common-mode

I have to design a power input filter of consumer device. It is powered with desktop AC/DC 12V power supply. Max current consumption - 1A. Device has a full metal enclosure. I am considering putting ESD and reverse polarity protection diodes in front, then use a cap-common mode choke-cap filter. Problem is that it is not clear to me how to approach selecting actual component values. Device may function as non grounded, but may get grounded through associated equipment, connected to a random enclosure spot.

I have a prototype with only a cap and inductor in series with positive lead. Negative lead is connected to chassis. Touching the prototype with a grounded wire scares uC. As there is only one wire coming to the device from power supply, I assume it is a common mode stuff that causes trouble.

I might as well isolate electronics from the metal enclosure and only connect input filter cap or a resistor from negative lead to the enclosure.

If anyone could guide me to the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to swallow a spider to catch a fly. You should concentrate making the uC more robust - if it has to connect to chassis that's OK but bring your isolated 12Vdc into the case and directly to the power pins that the uC PCB is attached to and if necessary add series L (and small R) and parallel C only to those wires before connecting to chassis.

Comment: Too much hand waving.  Draw a block diagram of the system.  It is not apparent at all why a filter on the power input is a good solution.

Comment: If you have ESD issues on the *power* input, you have something else very, very wrong.

Comment: OK, lets first concentrate on proper DC input circuit. I understand that my uC in the prototype is not robust enough and I am working on a solution.

Comment: To my knowledge, it needs common mode and diff. mode filtering just in case user has a bad EMI environment or grabs a noisy AC/DC power supply unit. The appliance has to be a robust one and any EMI should be stopped at the entry point to limit sec. emission. Problem is my limited experience on such task. I am not sure how I should take the enclosure, power supply parameters and possible other factors in to account when selecting L, R, C.

Comment: "Touching the prototype with a grounded wire scares uC. As there is only one wire coming to the device from power supply" - hang on, how is the ground from the PSU connected to the board?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The desktop AC/DC PSU is not grounded. Negative lead goes to GND and is connected to enclosure. Touching the enclosure with a ground wire of some other power-outlet-grounded equipment causes the trouble.

Comment: For reverse voltage protection, you generally want to use a power P-channel MOSFET wired in the FORWARD direction on the input positive, with the gate going to ground. When connected correctly, this power P-channel will conduct at its Rdson, which is typically measured in milli-ohms. When connected in reverse, the gate will have the wrong voltage, and the P-channel will not conduct, and the body diode blocks current, so it's protected. Another option is to add a crowbar power diode or transistor reverse biased between in/out, if you have a fused supply.

Comment: @JonWatte good old crowbars, I learned about them in The Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill, but never actually got to make and test one yet.

Comment: Latest revision of the filter/protection circuit has the following structure: fuse -> TVS -> CM choke -> cap || trisil -> LC filter -> active undervoltage/overvoltage/reverse protection circuitry. Trisil has slightly lower firing voltage than TVS thus if there is a over-voltage situation it fires before TVS, blows fuse and saves the day. On the other hand, if there is an ESD, TVS clamps if to a safe voltage and it does not reach the trisil through CM choke and does not blow anything unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved problems by doing things right:

1. Connected chassis to negative power supply lead where it enters the enclosure.
2. Ensured electronics insulation from chassis elsewhere
3. Ensured pieces of chassis are properly connected together
4. Will install Common-mode choke on power input to tame CM noise.

The problem was not with ESD, but with EMI (sorry for mentioning ESD at the first place). As the desktop supply is not grounded, it has +-160V 50Hz noise. When chassis gets grounded, massive voltage spike with huge dv/dt marches through the enclosure and gets coupled to all of the electronics inside. As a result, uC looses mind and reboots. With above mentioned measures, touching enclose with a grounded wire has no influence on operation.

Thank you for your accurate comments.